# Which Google apps can be deleted or disabled without harm to the system?

Tags: google, google-apps, delete

There's that common Google bloat ware on my smartphone's stock Android 6.0.1. I was wondering, what google apps I could savely either delete or at least deactivate without harming the OS's stability?

Device: bq Aquaris X5 Plus

OS: Android 6.0.1

All I actually need is the play store and for this, the google account. I've no intention to ever use gmail, drive, hangeouts, play music/books/games, google+ e.t.c., nor do I want to sync any data with google.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This very much depends on the device and the Android version running on it, plus where you've bought it – as the lot of pre-installed apps might differ based on that. I'm not sure about Gmail – but the other apps mentioned (Drive, Hangouts, Play Music/Books/Games, Google+) are the first ones I always disable, and never had any side effects. At least Music/Books/Games and G+ should be even safe to remove. You can also deactivate/disable the contacs sync adapter and calendar sync adapter if you don't plan to sync your contacts and calendars with Google.

What you definitely should ***not*** touch is the *Google Services Framework* – or you'll break "all things Google" on that device, including the Playstore.

If you want to get rid of almost all the crap, and don't need the ability to buy apps on Play or use apps that check their licenses against Google Services, flash a custom ROM and microG, plus install either Blankstore – or, if you need to buy apps and check their licenses, the original Playstore app. Details I have described in my article [Android without Google: microG](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-5a).

Comment: Just added device model an OS details to my original question.

Comment: @Bunjip Doesn't the Aquaris ship with CyanogenOS? If so, there is CyanogenMod available for it – and well, [it is even officially](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=paella). The cleanest way might be switching to that w/o GApps, then install microG, then Playstore (if needed) – as I already indicated with my answer. If you take that road, also have a look at [freecyngn](https://github.com/nvllsvm/freecyngn) :)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't ship with CyanogenOS (anymore) due to the change in [strategy of Cyanogen](https://cyngn.com/blog/the-future-of-cyanogen-and-the-untapped-power-of-mobile) who stopped to develop CyanogenOS but provide modular mods from now on only.

Comment: Still, as there is an official CM, it's a possible way. Just mentioning it, I don't say you *have to* go that path :)

Comment: don't get me wrong, I appreciate your hints ;). In fact, I'd love to use CM on my devices. Used to have CyanogenMod on my Oneplus One, which sadly passed away... However, I've learned I can't do without the play store. That's why I hesitate getting back CM and then still installing the google apps just to have this play store ...

Comment: Please take a look at my linked article then. µG is an open source replacement for the essential parts of the Google Services without all the "snooping stuff" (e.g. no analytics, no ads, no Google Fit, no Google Games – but full GCM support, fused locations, etc; see [implementation status](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/wiki/Implementation-Status) for what's available). I use that with BlankStore (as pointed out in my article), but it reportedly works with the "original Playstore app" as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go through your article for sure. Just need some time to ensure full awareness, so maybe I'll find that opportunity on the weekend. Thanks for pointing me there. 
Sieht auf jeden Fall gut aus beim Überfliegen ;)

Comment: Danke – Zeit zum "tiefer fliegen" :) If you then consider this answer as solving your issue, please don't forget to indicate so by marking it "accepted" :)

Answer (score 0):

you can disable that app like google hangouts, google play, maps, G drive, email, play games, play movies and play music. these stock apps consume more memory. there is no harmful effect on your device after removing this.

NOTE - But if you want to play any heavy game so it need google play services so you need to install it again.

Comment: What do you mean by "heavy games"? is Candy crush or similar games are considered heavy?